# What are NMOS level 1 CV equation and its main parameters?

Tags: mosfet, capacitance, nmos, modeling

I was asked to perform MOSFET CV modeling. I looked through some papers, but I still can't clarify what the CV model equation for a level-1 NMOS is, and I am also not sure what its main parameters are (maybe oxide capacitance, depletion capacitance, etc.)

Could you help me out?

Comment: Something like this https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/Analog-CMOS-Design/MOSFET-Fundamentals/C-V-Characteristics/ or this https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/current/postgraduate/regs/mpagswarwick/ex5/techniques/electronic/cv/

Comment: And perhaps this https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-720j-integrated-microelectronic-devices-spring-2007/pages/lecture-notes/   Lecture 29